# AVR 8bit, C standard compliance regarding bit accessing of SFRs

Tags: c, avr

One of my colleagues ran in some strange problems with programming an ATMega, related to accessing input - output ports.

Observing the problem after some research I concluded we should avoid accessing SFR's using operations which may compile to `SBI` or `CBI` instructions if we aim for a safe C standard compliant software. I am looking for *whether this decision was righteous or not*, so if my concerns here are valid.

The datasheet of the Atmel processor is [here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2466.pdf), it's an ATMega16. I will refer to some pages of this document below.

I will refer to the C standard using [the version found on this site](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/standards) under the WG14 N1256 link.

The `SBI` and `CBI` instructions of the processor operate at bit-level accessing only the bit in question. So they are not true Read-Modify-Write (R-M-W) instructions since they, as I understand, do not perform a read (of the targeted 8 bit SFR).

On page 50 of the above datasheet the first sentence begins like *All AVR ports have true Read-Modify-Write functionality...*, while ongoing it specifies that this only applies to accesses with the `SBI` and `CBI` instructions which technically are not R-M-W. The datasheet does **not** define what reading for example the `PORTx` registers are supposed to return (it however indicates that they are readable). So I assumed reading these SFRs are undefined (they might return the last thing written on them or the current input state or whatever).

On page 70 it lists some external interrupt flags, this is interesting because this is where the nature of the `SBI` and `CBI` instructions come to be important. The flags are set when an interrupt occurred, and they may be cleared by writing them to one. So if `SBI` was a true R-M-W instruction, it would clear all three flags regardless of the bit specified in the opcode.

And now let's get into the matters of C.

The compiler itself is truly irrelevant, the only important fact is that it might use the `CBI` and `SBI` instructions in certain situations which I think make it non-compliant.

In the above mentioned C99 standard, the section *5.1.2.3 Program execution*, point 2 and 3 refers to this (on page 13), and *6.7.3 Type qualifiers*, point 6 (on page 109). The latter mentions that *What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined*, however a few phrases before it requires that *any expression referring to such an object shall be evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine*.

Also note that hardware ports such as that used in the example are declared `volatile` in the appropriate headers.

Example:

```
PORTA |= 1U << 6;
```

This is known to translate to an `SBI`. This implies that only a Write access happens on the volatile (`PORTA`) object. However if one would write:

```
var = 6;
...
PORTA |= 1U << var;
```

That would not translate to an `SBI` even though it will still only set one bit (since `SBI` has the bit to set encoded in the opcode). So this will expand to a true R-M-W sequence with a potentially different result than above (in the case of `PORTA` this is undefined behaviour as far as I could deduct from the datasheet).

By the C standard this behaviour might or might not be permitted. It is messy in that term too that here two things happen which mix in. One, the more apparent is the lack of the Read access in one of the cases. The other, less apparent is how the Write is performed.

If the compiled code omits the Read, it might fail to trigger hardware behaviour which is tied to such an access. However the AVR as far as I know has no such mechanism, so it might pass by the standard.

The Write is more interesting, however it also takes in the Read.

Omitting the Read in the case of using `SBI` implies that the affected SFR's must all work like latches (or any bit not working like so is either tied to 0 or 1), so the compiler can be sure of what it would read from them if it actually did the access. If this was not be the case then the compiler would at least be buggy. By the way this also clashes with that the datasheet did not define what is read from the `PORTx` registers.

How the write is performed is also a source of inconsistency: the result is different depending on how the compiler compiles it (a `CBI` or `SBI` affecting only one bit, a byte write affecting all bits). So writing code to clear / set one bit might either "work" (as in not "accidentally" clearing interrupt flags), or not if the compiler produces a true R-M-W sequence instead.

Maybe these are technically permitted by the C standard (as "implementation defined" behaviour, and the compiler deducting these cases that the Read access is not necessary to the volatile object), but at least I would consider it a buggy or inconsistent implementation.

Another example:

```
PORTA = PORTA | (1U << 6);
```

It is clearly visible that normally to conform with the standard a Read and then a Write of `PORTA` should be carried out. While according to the behaviour of `SBI`, it will lack a Read access, although as above this may pass for a mix of implementation defined behaviour and the compiler deducting that the Read is unnecessary here. (Or was my assumption wrong? That is assuming `a |= b` identical to `a = a | b`?)

So based on these I settled with that we should avoid these types of code as it is (or may be in the future) unclear how they might behave depending on whether the compiler would use `SBI` or `CBI`, or a true R-M-W sequence.

To tell the truth I mostly went after various forum posts etc. resolving this, not analysing actual compiler output. Not my project after all (and now I am not at work). I accepted it reading [AVRFreaks](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=294615) for example that AVR-GCC would output these instructions in the above mentioned situations which alone may pose a problem even if with the actual version we used we wouldn't observe this. (However I think this case it stood as my suggestion to implement port accesses using a shadow work variables fixed the problems my colleague observed)

**Note**: I edited the middle based on some research on the C (C99) standard.

**Edit**: Reading [the AVR Libc FAQ](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/FAQ.html) I again found something which contradicts the automatic use of `SBI` or `CBI`. It is the last question & answer where it specifically states that since the ports are declared `volatile` the compiler can not optimize out the read access, *according to the rules of the C language* (as it phrases).

I also understand that it is very unlikely that this particular behaviour (that is using `SBI` or `CBI`) would directly introduce bugs, but by masking "bugs" it may introduce very nasty ones in the long run if someone accidentally generalizes based on this behaviour while not understanding the AVR at assembly level.

Comment: And what exactly where these strange problems that occur only if a register is not read before its content is changed?

Comment: He was trying to interface a parallel alphanumeric LCD. We had  experience with these from earlier with PIC18s using C, I originally recommended him to just take one of those and port it. The LCD did not work (like if we did not communicate with it at all). Then looking in the problem and skimming through the ported code I concluded this, he did it, and the LCD worked as the code dictated. In the prev. code there were stuff like `PORTC |= (1U << 6) | (1U << 7);` which obviously won't translate to `SBI`, so true R-M-W happens, then see above. Datasheet does not define R from PORTx.

Comment: C99, 6.7.3/6 "What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified type is implementation-defined." So maybe `PORTA |= ..` is not seen as an access? (You're right that `PORTA |= ..` is defined as `PORTA = PORTA | ..` where `PORTA` is only evaluated once, as per 6.5.16.2/3.)

Comment: Interesting question, bookmarked. I may even break-out the development board after dinner to have a play around myself. (yeah, I know the pun was awful) I've got a feeling that rather than `PORTA = PORTA | 1 << 6`, that you should instead be doing `PORTA = PINA | 1 << 6` - This is based on C code from page 72 of the atMega64.pdf file I have, whose original url escapes me now. After downloading the 16's datasheet you linked to, I see that the same example is given on page 54.

Comment: An interesting effect which sure is visible if you try to clear interrupt flags (datasheet pg. 70). If you do one like `GIFR |= 1U << 6;` then it will "work" (only the intended flag will clear). However if you attempt to clear two like `GIFR |= (1U << 6) | (1U << 7);`, then all 3 will clear, and bang, you have a bug in there. From C level I would except these two behave similarly (either both clearing all flags due to R-M-W or both clearing only the flags I explicitly specified) however it is clearly not the case here.

Comment: I am surprised that reading PORTx would give anything unexpected. Fig. 23 of the datasheet (p. 51) shows the PORTx flip-flops to be wired like a simple storage register: a read access (signal RRx) sends the flip-flop's contents to the bus.

Comment: Now that I see this (Edgar's) comment, as I recall, after about a half year some of us noticed that the figure clarifies it. All in all, it still took months for a group involving two electrical engineers (neither is me) to spot this. The question turns kind of hypothetical with this since the actual behavior of the compiler after all, as far as I see right now won't likely break anything, but still has some validity (the CPU could have a feature which could unintentionally be broken by this).

Answer (score 3):

You should probably stop trying to apply the C memory model to I/O registers. They are not plain memory. In the case of PORTn registers, it is in fact irrelevant whether it is a single bit write or a R-M-W operation unless you're mixing in interrupts. If you do read-modify-write an interrupt may alter state in between, causing a race condition; but that would be exactly the same issue for memory. The advantage of the SBI/CBI instructions there is that they are atomic.

The PORTn registers are readable, and also drive the output buffers. They are not different functions on read and write (as on PIC), but a normal register. Newer PICs also have the output registers readable on LAT addresses, precisely so you won't need a shadow variable. Other SFRs such as PINn or interrupt flags have more complicated behaviour. On recent AVRs, writing to PINn instead toggles bits in PORTn, which again is useful for its fast and atomic operation. Writing 1s to interrupt flag registers clears them, again to prevent race conditions.

The point is, these features are in place to produce *correct* behaviour for hardware aware programs, even if some of it looks odd in C code (i.e. using `reg=_BV(2);` instead of `reg&=~_BV(2);`). Precise compliance with the C standard is an impractical goal when the code is by its very nature hardware specific (though semantic similarity does help, which the interrupt flag behaviour fails at). Wrapping the odd constructs in inline functions or macros with names that explain what they truly do is probably a good idea, or at least commenting what the effects are. A set of such I/O routines could also form the basis of a hardware abstraction layer that may help you port code.

Trying to interpret the C specification strictly here is also rather confusing, as it doesn't admit to addressing bits (which is what SBI and CBI do), and digging through my old (1992) copy finds that volatile accesses may result in several implementation defined behaviours, *including* the possibility of *no accesses at all*.

Comment: Wrapping in macros is the way how it should work I think. The problem with the current approach is inconsistency (like `GIFR |= 1U << 6;` and `var = 6; ... GIFR |= 1U << var;` producing fundamentally different results), not to mention that how I can be sure that through optimization or various layers of indirections the expansion to `SBI` or `CBI` won't fail. So I would except these constructs resolving to R-M-W while having macros for the delicate stuff which have their well-known constraints and can be expected to work reliably.